# iOS Objective C View Controller Not Using Properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

Let's say I have a simple app that is loading data into a table view. It then allows you to view details (etc).

My table view controller on first load looks something like this below.

Notice I am not using an "property" declarations for these variables. Is this OK? Are there any disadvantages regarding the way memory is then handled?

```
@interface TblVC ()
{
    MBProgressHUD *hudLoad; // new up loading while I go get data
    NSMutableArray *results; // set to results after loading data
    CLLocationManager *locManager; // get location in view load
}
@end

@implementation TblVC
{
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // spin up the above variables here which can then be used in other methods inside view controller
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use properties. There is absolutely no reason to use the old-style instance variables anymore.

Apple's documentation on properties goes into detail about the benefits. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html

Answer (score 0):

An instance variable is unique to a class. By default, only the class and subclasses can access it. Therefore, as a fundamental principal of object-oriented programming, instance variables (ivars) are private—they are encapsulated by the class.

By contrast, a property is a public value that may or may not correspond to an instance variable. If you want to make an ivar public, you'd probably make a corresponding property. But at the same time, instance variables that you wish to keep private do not have corresponding properties, and so they cannot be accessed from outside of the class. You can also have a calculated property that does not correspond to an ivar…

Without a property, ivars can be kept hidden. In fact, unless an ivar is declared in a public header it is difficult to even determine that such an ivar exists.

A simple analogy would be a shrink-wrapped book. A property might be the title, author or hardcover vs. softcover. The "ivars" would be the actual contents of the book. You don't have access to the actual text until you own the book; you don't have access to the ivars unless you own the class.